# remove characters from a python string

Tags: python, regex

I have several python strings from which I want unwanted characters removed.

Examples:

```
"This is '-' a test" 
     should be "This is a test"
"This is a test L)[_U_O-Y OH : l’J1.l'}/"
     should be "This is a test"
"> FOO < BAR" 
     should be "FOO BAR"
"I<<W5§!‘1“¢!°\" I" 
     should be "" 
     (because if only words are extracted then it returns I W I and none of them form words)
"l‘?£§l%nbia  ;‘\\~siI.ve_rswinq m"
     should be ""
"2|'J]B"
     should be ""
```

this is what I have so far, however, it is not keeping the original spaces between words.

```
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","This is '-' a test")
>>> line
'Thisisatest'
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","This is a test L)[_U_O-Y OH : l’J1.l'}/")
>>> line
'ThisisatestL_U_OYOHlJ1l' 
#although i would prefer this to be "This is a test" but if not possible i would 
 prefer "This is a test L_U_OYOHlJ1l"
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","> FOO < BAR")
>>> line
'FOOBAR'
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","I<<W5§!‘1“¢!°\" I")
>>> line
'IW51I'
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","l‘?£§l%nbia  ;‘\\~siI.ve_rswinq m")  
>>> line
'llnbiasiIve_rswinqm'
>>> line = re.sub(r"\W+","","2|'J]B")
>>> line
'2JB'
```

I will be filtering the regex cleaned words through a list of predefined words later.

Comment: There are one-letter words, though - "I" and "a"/"A"

Comment: **Updated** In this case I won't be matching against a dictionary of words but a predefined list of words. So yeah, if "I" is in the predefined list then that would be ok...

Comment: Deleted my answer, since I didn't observe the word extraction requirement carefully. Though, for string "l‘?£§l%nbia  ;‘\\~siI.ve_rswinq m", shouldn't any word be extracted?

Comment: `r'[^\w\s]+'` will match all non-word non-space characters ...

Comment: Would it be correct to describe you filter as "split the string on spaces, remove all elements containing non-alphabetic characters, join them on spaces"?

Comment: @Noctua as I was writing the question that did come to mind. I am trying that solution now.

Comment: You could first run a sub on `r'[^A-Z\s]+ *'` (with ignore case) and then check the results against words from the predefined list you mentioned in a comment above.

Comment: This is a tough one. Its the flip side of "What is a text word". When you describe what is text, just match it then write it to another string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a split and filter, like this:

```
' '.join(word for word in line.split() if word.isalpha() and word.lower() in list)
```

This will remove all non-alphabetic words and alphabetic words that are not in the list.

Examples:

```
def myfilter(string):
    words = {'this', 'test', 'i', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'}
    return ' '.join(word for word in line.split() if word.isalpha() and word.lower() in words)

>>> myfilter("This is '-' a test")
'This a test'
>>> myfilter("This is a test L)[_U_O-Y OH : l’J1.l'}/")
'This a test'
>>> myfilter("> FOO < BAR")
'FOO BAR'
>>> myfilter("I<<W5§!‘1“¢!°\" I")
'I'
>>> myfilter("l‘?£§l%nbia  ;‘\\~siI.ve_rswinq m")
''
>>> myfilter("2|'J]B")
''
```

Comment: This is a good answer since it scales well, but with two adjustments.  1) the `list` should be a `set`, for O(1) lookups.  2) Don't shadow built-in types with local variables (list).

Comment: @roippi: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll incorparate them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one clears out any group of non-space symbols with at least one non alphabetic character. It will leaves some unwanted group of letters though :

```
re.sub(r"\w*[^a-zA-Z ]+\w*","","This is a test L)[_U_O-Y OH : l’J1.l'}/")
```

gives :

```
'This is a test  OH  '
```

It will also leave groups of more than one space :

```
re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z ]+\w*","","This is '-' a test")
'This is  a test'  # two spaces
```